# How can i connect Optaplanner to MS SQL Server?

Tags: java, database, optaplanner

I'm trying to connect Optaplanner to my SQL database. does anyone know how to do this? or where I can find out how to do this?

Comment: Please be more specific than that. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried? What were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be to hard to switch [optaplanner-quickstarts](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts)'s `quarkus-school-timetabling` quickstart to use MySQL instead [using this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource).

Answer (score 1):

I myself would start reading the chapter on Integration in the OptaPlanner User Guide (I can't figure out from your question if you'd already have consulted that part) ?